# UILabels in Custom UITableViewCell not rendering on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, interface-builder

Hello and thank you for your help. I have a custom UITableViewCell and the controller of the class is written in Swift. All of the init functions are being called on creation of the cell however on inspection in the debugger all of the lables and the one image view i have added to the content view have a frame of 0.

here is the file containing the tableView:

```
class SearchesMainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var contentTableView: UITableView?
var tableViewData = SearchesMainTableViewData()

 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

internal override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Search"

    var nib = UINib(nibName: "SingleSearchTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    contentTableView?.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: SingleSearchTableViewCellController.reuseID())

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.numberOfSectionsInTableView()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.numberOfRowsInTableSection(section)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell:SingleSearchTableViewCellController = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SingleSearchTableViewCellController.reuseID()) as SingleSearchTableViewCellController
    cell.formatCell()
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 54.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return tableViewData.headerViewForSection(section)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableViewData.heightForTableViewSectionHeaders()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableViewData.heightForTableViewSectionFooters()
}
}
```

here is the controller for the cell:

```
class SingleSearchTableViewCellController : UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var dateMonthLable : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var dateDayLable : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var yearLable : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var makeModelLable : UILabel?

var search : Search = Search()

class func reuseID() -> String{
    return "SingleSearchTableViewCell"
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

init(previousSearch s : Search){
    search = s
    super.init()
}

func formatCell(){
    formatDateMonthLable()
    formatDateDayLable()
    formatYearRangeLable()
    formatMakeModelLable()
}

private func formatDateMonthLable(){

}

private func formatDateDayLable(){

}

private func formatYearRangeLable(){

}

private func formatMakeModelLable(){

}
}
```

and an image of the tableview cell in interface builder with all of the bindings:

[image]

Thanks a lot for any sugestions or help, I am new with both Swift and interface builder. Have a nice day :)

**Edit**
What is actualy built from this code
[image]

It seams like every other place I use nibs there is an initWithNib or something along those lines, and there is nothing like that for tableview cells. I think the linking of data and view may be off or missing something.

Comment: Are the frames actually 0, or is that just what the debugger is saying?

Comment: When you are working with auto layout, you don't need to take a care about frames, the auto layout will do that for you. I can't see you send data to cells, are you sending data correctly in your app?

Comment: rdelmar-I added a screenshot of the output of the code

Comment: jan cassio - i am not sending data to the cells, I am exspecting the place holder text in interface builder to show up on every cell, in the debugger I can see the value in each label is the same string as in the interface builder preview

Comment: Is the cell id defined in Interface Builder?

Comment: so the cell has a Custom Class of SingleSearchTableViewCellController however there is a field below that called Identity with the label of Restoration ID. This Restoration ID is blank and I am not sure what that value is.

Comment: Did you set the `datasource` and `delegate` properties of your tableView to your viewController class in interface builder?

Comment: Yes, Cell for row at index path as well as did select row, number of rows are all being called and populated correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your init overrides in the cell class. I'm not that familiar with Swift, so I don't know why having those in there with nothing but calls to super causes your subview not to show. Since you're not doing anything in those methods (or awakeFromNib either), you should delete them. I think that will fix your problem (it did in my tests).

Comment: what version of xcode are you using? I only added them because I was getting a compile time error that I was missing them and they had to be in my implementation. The version of xcode I am using is 6.1

Comment: This gets me wondering ... what is in your non over ridden functions that is not in my call to super.xyz ... anything in a non over ridden function should be getting called when I call super in addition to the code i could put there

Comment: @CWineland, I don't know why your code should be any different than not implementing those methods at all. All I know, is that the problem went away when I deleted all the init methods. I don't know if this is some issue that's specific to Swift since init methods are fundamentally different (don't return anything) from the objective-C ones.

Comment: It is a good possibility that you need them in swift and not Obj-c for that reason. I am doing this project in swift for learning more then anything. I will create the same thing in Obj-c to test this, if so Im not sure were to take this issue

Comment: @CWineland, I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Did you try getting rid of all the init methods? That's what I did, and that is fine in Swift.

Comment: what version of xcode do you have? in 6.1 the code will not compile unless you have the init methods in the class.

Comment: Ok so this does work, the reason I was getting a compile error was because of my init(previousSearch s : Search) that also can not be there without the other overriden inits.
My new question is Why Why Why lol, i am calling super.xyz in all of the inits, what could be left out that not over riding them gets called

Comment: @CWineland, Ok, I figured it out. Your override of initWithCoder is wrong -- you need to call super.init(coder: aDecoder), not just super.init(). If you change that, then leaving in all the overrides works (although there's no need to have them if you're not going to do anything other than call super). Also, when you have the correct initWithCoder in there, the other init methods are not called, so you really should only override initWithCoder if you want to do any further initialization.